# Order by quarter of hour in the same column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have results like this (order by Year, DayOfYear, Hour):

```sql
Year    DayOfYear   Hour
2012    266         13:00
2012    266         13:15
2012    266         13:30
2012    266         15:15
2012    266         15:30
2012    266         16:00
```

I need to retrive the rows order by the *quarter of hour* and then for *hour* like this:

```sql
Year    DayOfYear   Hour
2012    266         13:00
2012    266         16:00
2012    266         13:15
2012    266         15:15
2012    266         13:30
2012    266         15:30
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially you can just order by the minute, since this will be 0, 15, 30, or 45.

```sql
ORDER BY Year, DayOfYear, DATEPART(MINUTE, Hour), Hour;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DATEPART(mi, CONVERT(DATETIME, hour))` in your SELECT list and sort on this.

Comment: I strongly recommend you spell out the datepart as `minute` instead of using shorthand. Shorthand just leads to confusion. Also the convert isn't really necessary - if the string can't be implicitly converted to datetime it will fail with or without it.

Comment: right @AaronBertrand, didn't know about this. Thanks (confusion between mi and mm happens often).

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to 15 minute intervals with:

```
datediff(minute, 0, Hour) / 15 % 4
```

Or in a query:

```
select  *
,       datediff(minute, 0, Hour) / 15 % 4 as Quarter
from    YourTable
order by
        datediff(minute, 0, Hour) / 15 % 4
```

This prints:

```
Year        DayOfYear   Hour             Quarter
----------- ----------- ---------------- -----------
2012        266         13:00:00         0
2012        266         16:00:00         0
2012        266         13:15:00         1
2012        266         15:15:00         1
2012        266         15:30:00         2
2012        266         13:30:00         2

(6 row(s) affected)
```